# How can we execute First Two Migration files out of three using C# code?

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.1

**I want to execute top two migration files in sequence order out of three files**

like we have files
Migration_1
Migration_2
Migration_3

It works fine with package manager console with the command
**Update-Database Migration_2**

but I want to do same from C# code side
I have tried below command but it runs all three pending migrations files in sequence order
**DbContext.Database.Migrate();**

Comment: Just modify the loop from the answer of the linked post to break after applying the last desired migration.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate **question**. This is a completly different question with a similar answer (slightly diffrente) from other question. You should create a new answer with the loop and the break and refer the post as the source.